# uses-feature overruling uses-permission?

Tags: android, google-play

My app does read SMS and react on incoming calls, but I still want tablet users to be able to download it from Android Market because it does a whole lot more than that.

So, if my app requests permissions for reading the phone's state and SMS, but I do tell the Android Market that my app doesn't use telephony APIs, what would the Android Market do then?

```
<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />

<uses-feature
    android:required="false"
    android:name="android.hardware.telephony" />
```

Filtered for WIFI-only tablets or not filtered, that is the question.

Any experiences?

Have a great day
Tom

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Given your manifest elements above, the Market should allow the app to be visible for WiFi-only tablets as well as phones. The Ruboto IRB application ran into this shortly after the XOOM became available. [Here is a blog post](http://commonsware.com/blog/2011/02/25/xoom-permissions-android-market.html) I wrote up after helping them fix matters.